# Creating dynamic array in a class using make_unique in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create a dynamic array using this format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory>  // for make_unique?

using std::make_unique;
using std::string;

class Kitchen
{
private:

    auto dynamicArray = make_unique<string[]>(10);
```

This is in my Kitchen.h file.

The error that shows up is: 'auto' cannot be used here. I'm not sure if this is because I am using "auto" under private, or perhaps it cannot be used in a .h file.

Comment: Perhaps because my constructor is empty?

Comment: `auto` can not be used for class members. Use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Also it should be `#include <string>` instead of `#include <string.h>` which is totally different.

Comment: Galik - can I use auto in the class cpp file?
Barmak Shemirani - Thanks for the catch!

Comment: You can use auto to declare a member variable. Why are you doing thus anyway, instead of using a vector?

Comment: @Galik: `auto` can certainly be used for class members, if they are member function.  Just not data members.  And `std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>` is perfectly acceptable for an array that doesn't need to be resized or copied, not every scenario needs `std::vector`.

Comment: @BenVoigt A vector is basically designed for this. It's hard to see why one would choose a smart pointer to an array instead of a vector - which is basically a smart pointer to an array but with less hassle and more (cost free) features.

Comment: @OP Quit torturing yourself and just use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you want a dynamic array, why dont you use a std::vector? Look the example below and initialize the vector in the constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Kitchen {
public:
  Kitchen() {}
private:

  std::vector<std::string> dynamicArray;
}
```

I think that if you need something different than this, you should give us a lot more details.

Answer (score 1):

First, the C compatibility header `<string.h>` is wrong for use of `std::string`. Include `<string>` for that.

Second, a non-`static` class data member can't be declared `auto`. E.g. the g++ compiler reacts this way:

```
error: non-static data member declared 'auto'
```

Third, just use `std::vector` for a dynamic size array. It's copyable. A `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable.